# Android system wide nofiles(descriptors) limit

Tags: android, linux-kernel, file-descriptor, ulimit

Is there any way to set system wide nofiles(descriptors) limit - like editing `/etc/security/limits.conf`file in linux?

I have root access to system - so access rights is not problem

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any solution to do this system wide, but found terminal command `prlimit ${PID}  7  SOFT HARD` where PID is Process ID of your app. SOFT and HARD are soft and hard limits.

But be careful - there are some software in android which will not work if you have too much opened FD. I personnally met such kind of errors (for chromium web view):

`Abort message: 'FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE'`

But decreasing limit works good for me allowing to meet "Too many open files" much quicker =)